# Как получить доступ к открытой (pub) константе модуля?

Tags: rust, const, mod

Какими способами можно получить доступ к константе модуля?
Например, есть в модуле `std::u8` две константы `MIN, MAX`. Какие синтаксические кострукции можно ипользовать, чтобы получить доступ к ним? Пожалуйста, приведите пример!

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант ответа:

*lib.rs:*

```
#[cfg(test)]

    mod tests {
        #[test]
        fn it_works() {

            const MIN:u8 = ::std::u8::MIN;

            assert_eq!(MIN, 0);
        }
    }
```